# How to read a google drive file with Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, readfile

I'm working on an app that takes a random line from a file on Google Drive. I don't know how to make python read the file, because the file should not be on your computer but on Google Drive.

I tried to use the `open()` function, but that didn't work:

```
accLink = r'[My Google Drive link]'
def getAccount(link):
    f = open(link, 'r')
    f.readlines()
    print(f)
getAccount(accLink)
```

How should I make Python read a file on Google Drive?

Comment: Set up the API with this guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: you have to use their API, there are a lot of packages such as https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/ for shorting your task , By judging context of your question. It seems like you are a complete newbie in dev.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider installing PyDrive from Github and use it in your Python script.

You can take a look at https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have one problem. PyDrive only has a CreateFile() function, but how can you make Python **read** an already existing file?

Comment: You have the answer in the Readme file of this Github repo, section: File Management made easy. file3.GetContentFile .......